# Naming 1, 2, 3, ... millennial celebrations

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I know that after 100 years there are centennial celebrations, after 200 years bicentennial, [tricentennial](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tricentennial), etc.,

Similarly, are there terms for 2000, 3000, etc., years of celebration?

Comment: Er, [tercentennial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tercentenary).

Comment: @HaL, [tricentennial](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tricentennial) is okay too, I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are, and they follow the same naming convention:

[bimillennial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bimillennial), [trimillennial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trimillennial), etc.

Comment: I doubt many of us will be around long enough to need to expand that **etc.**...

Comment: Perhaps not you & I, but if all goes well this *question* will still be around in some form or another `:)`

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Picking up where you left off, we have:

- 250 years - Sestercentennial
- 300 years - Tercentennial
- 400 years - Quadricentennial
- 500 years - Quincentennial
- 600 years - Sexcentennial
- 700 years - Septcentennial
- 800 years - Octocentennial
- 900 years - Nonacentennial
- 1000 years - Millennial
- 2000 years  - Bimillennial

Anything beyond bimillenial is probably very uncommon at best, but you could likely follow the above naming convention and be understood. See more odd usages [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anniversary).

Comment: The [2500 year celebration of the Persian empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,500_year_celebration_of_the_Persian_Empire) by the Shah of Iran in 1971...what would they call that? Sestermillenial?

Comment: @Mitch I'll buy it.

Answer (score 1):

Those would be *millennial* celebrations.

Party like it's 2999!

Answer (score 0):

For a thousand years, the word is *millennial*. For two thousand years, the word is *bimillennial*. See this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anniversary#Anniversary_names) on anniversary names. I would imagine the same pattern goes for the higher thousands, e.g. *trimillennial*, *quadrimillennial*, and so forth.